# When using Faker in laravel, how to test the results of API calls?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-5, faker

I want to write tests for API calls in Laravel. I have created a model factory to seed my test database so the API calls can return something. Inside the model factory I use Faker to generate random data for the model attributes. I'm using this factory at the beginning of my test, so the data is created during runtime.

How can I  test the results of the API calls? The problem is that during every execution of the test the API call can return different results, due to the randomly generated data. So I cannot just save the result of an APi call in a .json file and compare it with the actual result of the API call in the test.

I am aware of the `seeJsonStructure()`method ( https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing#verifying-structural-match ) but I do not want to use it.

So this is my current attempt which does not work:

```php
$cars = factory(Car::class)->times(2)->create();

$this->json('GET', '/api/cars');

$expected = File::get('cars.json');

$this->seeJson((array) json_decode($expected));
```

Comment: What is the reason behind not using `seeJsonStructure()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could set a seed value in Faker as described [here](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#seeding-the-generator).

> ## Seeding the Generator
>
> You may want to get always the same generated data - for instance when using Faker for unit testing purposes. The generator offers a `seed()` method, which seeds the random number generator. Calling the same script twice with the same seed produces the same results.
>
> ```php
> <?php
> $faker = Faker\Factory::create();
> $faker->seed(1234);
>
> echo $faker->name; // 'Jess Mraz I';
> ```

That will give you consistent results across test runs.

Comment: Note that this will work as long as faker only creates one model instance at all or if the model does not have attributes that are supposed to be unique or if the model is not persisted to the database. Because obviously faker will always use the same values for the unique attribute which will cause an SQL error when persisting the second model.

My solution is to use PHP's `srand(0)` function before using faker to create the models, so faker will create random attributes for each model, but they will not change between each time you run the tests.

Comment: @chris342423 As long as you use the same faker instance and don't set the seed again sequential calls to a faker method should return different values.